# Ошибка Cannot find module 'gulp-jade'

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, npm, jade

Система Windows 8, nodejs -v 6.9.4
npm -v 3.10.10
gulp [01:25:49] CLI version 1.2.2

Уже второй день мучаюсь с галпом, первая проблема была: cmd не видит команду gulp, проблему решил добавили системные переменные, при том ,что npm был установлен в dir C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm, а не C:\%Username%\AppData\Roaming\npm. Возникла новая проблема, с отсутствием данных файлов при вызове команда gulp, в корне dir с проектом, пробовал решение на инострнанном stackoverflow по переустановке, не помогло, прошу помощи у русского -говорящего комьюнити, заранее благодарен

```
    B:\web>gulp
    module.js:471
     throw err;
  ^

 Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-jade'
 at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (B:\web\gulpfile.js:3:12)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

код в
      packege.json

```
"name": "web",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"private": true,
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
"gulp": "gulp"
},
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"devDependencies": {
"gulp": "^3.9.1",
"gulp-imagemin": "^3.1.1",
"gulp-util": "^3.0.8"
},
"repository": {
  "type": "git",
  "url": "http://github.com/npm/npm.git"
}
```

}

Comment: У Вас же `gulp-jade` не обнаружен в `devDependencies`. И `gulpfile.js` неплохо увидеть.

Comment: `var gulp = require('gulp'); var jade = require('gulp-jade'); var util = require('gulp-util'); var paths ={ jade: { src: 'src/markups/*.jade', dist: 'dist/pages' } } gulp.task('jade', function() { var YOUR_LOCALS = {}; gulp.src(paths.jade.src) .pipe(jade({ locals: YOUR_LOCALS, pretty: ' ' })) .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.jade.dist)) }); gulp.task('watch', function () { gulp.watch(paths.jade.src, ['jade']) }); gulp.task('default', ['jade'],['watch']);`

Answer (score 0):

Ну так и верно, в `packege.json` нет `gulp-jade`. А в `gulpfile.js` он ещё наверняка и не подключен? Нужно такое прикладывать, когда ошибка может крыться в обычном `require`.
Чтобы установить `gulp-jade`, необходимо выполнить такую команду:
`npm install --save-dev gulp-jade`
А чтобы просмотреть список пакетов без лишних зависимостей  **конкретно в папке проекта**, можно глянуть через:
`npm ls --depth=0`

Comment: `var gulp = require('gulp');
var jade = require('gulp-jade');
var util = require('gulp-util');
var paths ={
    jade: {
        src: 'src/markups/*.jade',
        dist: 'dist/pages'
    }
}
gulp.task('jade', function() {
    var YOUR_LOCALS = {};
    gulp.src(paths.jade.src)
        .pipe(jade({
            locals: YOUR_LOCALS,
            pretty: '  '
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.jade.dist))
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch(paths.jade.src, ['jade'])
});

gulp.task('default', ['jade'],['watch']);`

Comment: npm ls --depth=0
+-- gulp-install@0.6.0
+-- gulp-jade@1.1.0
`-- gulp-pug@3.2.0
в директории с проектом данная команда выдает ошибку

Comment: @oleja, ну у меня не вызвала) И вывела `gulp-jade`

Comment: @oleja, а ты не пробовал удалить папку npm в проекте? Удали и запусти `npm install`, чтобы все зависимости и пакеты установились только нужные.

Comment: пробовал, теперь
 `Using gulpfile B:\web\gulpfile.js
[12:52:19] Starting 'jade'...
[12:52:19] 'jade' errored after 11 ms
[12:52:19] Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'B:\web\content.json' `

отсутствует файл контент, но разве он нужен для первичной копиляции ?

Comment: @oleja, не думаю, что вообще нужен, я о таком вообще не слышал. У меня в корне папки проекта он отсутствует.

Comment: Добавил `content.json`, чудесным образом начало все работать, но я подозреваю, что работает неправильно

Answer (score 0):

> Уже второй день мучаюсь с галпом, первая проблема была: cmd не видит команду gulp, проблему решил добавили системные переменные, при том ,что npm был установлен в dir C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm, а не C:\%Username%\AppData\Roaming\npm.

Для этого надо сделать команду `npm i -g gulp-cli`.
Для работы с гайп, его нужно установить глобально и локально. Когда вы так делаете, галп который вызван через `gulp` обращается к галпу глобальному, а этот в свою очередь ищет в той папке которой вы вызывали галп, галп локальный.

> Возникла новая проблема, с отсутствием данных файлов при вызове команда gulp, в корне dir с проектом, пробовал решение на инострнанном stackoverflow по переустановке, не помогло, прошу помощи у русского -говорящего комьюнити, заранее благодарен

На каждый плагин который вы хотите использовать, вы должны его устанавливать `npm i --save plugin-name` (`npm i --save gulp-jade` например).